# Adding text to a figure - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, slider, matlab-figure

I wrote a code that shows a figure devided to 2 parts; 
the first one showing the main image, and the second one is a slider showing the rest of the images.

Now I need to add text to the main part (Like "Help" or "guide" text).
How can I do it?

This is my main sub-code:

```
    %# design GUI
    numSubs = 10; % Num of sub-images.
    mx = numImgs-numSubs+1;
    hFig = figure('Menubar','none');

    % The Main Image:
       hAx = axes('Position',[0 0.3 1 0.8], 'Parent',hFig);
hMainImg = imshow(img, 'Parent',hAx);

    % the slider
    hPanel = uipanel('Position',[0 0.04 1 0.26], 'Parent',hFig);
    uicontrol('Style','slider', 'Parent',hFig, ...
        'Callback',@slider_callback, ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 0.04], ...
        'Value',1, 'Min',1, 'Max',mx, 'SliderStep',[1 10]./mx);


    subImg = zeros(numSubs,1);
    for i=1:numSubs
        %# create axis, show frame, hookup click callback
        hAx = axes('Parent',hPanel, ...
            'Position',[(i-1)/numSubs 0 1/numSubs 1]);
        % Load img number i
        name=frames(i).name;
        img=imread(name,'jpg');
        subImg(i) = imshow(img, 'Parent',hAx);
        value = i;
        set(subImg(i), 'ButtonDownFcn',{@click_callback value})
        axis(hAx, 'normal')
        hold off;
    end
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this construction:

```
hT = uicontrol('style', 'text', 'string', 'HELLO WORLD', 'position', [...])
```

It will create static text in the figure at position `position`. You can use all the regular options for `uicontrols` like `'parent'` or `'units'`.

However, since your image is in an `axis`, the better/easier way to do it is using

```
hT = text(X, Y, 'HELLO WORLD')
```

with `X` and `Y` the desired coordinates of the text *in the axes*.

You can set additional options via `set`:

```
set(hT, 'color', 'r', 'backgroundcolor', 'k', 'fontsize', 10, ...)
```

You can get a list of all options by issuing `set(hT)` on a mock `text` object.

Comment: @Rode Oldenhuis: I tried both, the first one didn't work. If I don't choose a position it shows me the first letter of the text in the bottom of the figure. Else, if I do choose the position, it doesn't show me the text at all. The second one "hT=text(...) doesn't show me a text at all. it shows me Axes on the image !!
Any idea why?
And thanks for answering.

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh Did you try the `uicontrol` or the `text`-command?

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh what `position` did you give?

Comment: @RodeOldenhuis, I tried different positions, for example:[0 0.4 1 0.6]. Is it a wrong position?

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh Positions are tricky, especially when you're showing an image in your axes. The coordinate bases (origin) is then at the top-left instead of bottom-left. Also, because images are generally big (as in, a few thousand pixels either way), the standard fontsize of 12 may not be enough. Just try `text(..., 'fontsize', 50)` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh You can also use something like `gg = gtext('SOME TEXT')` to place some text in your axes with the mouse. Then `get(gg, 'position')` to get its position.

Comment: Thanks. I tried: hT = text(0.75, 0.8, 'HELLO WORLD')
   set(hT, 'color', 'r', 'backgroundcolor', 'k', 'fontsize', 12);
it does work, but shows me an AXES in the background (at the image). Do you know why is that?

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh Hmm...Can't confirm that here (I get no axes). You can always use `axis off` to work around it.